# ReactJS Add in Component based on a number user inputs

Tags: reactjs

Hello so I have a input called steps and if the user enters say 5 steps then I want to display a prebuilt component 5 times and send different data into each of those 5 components.

Right now I have this but it just doesn't work at all or I just show one render of the component box and not 5. I'm using hooks fyi. steps is the value the user enters into the input.

```
 <div>
     {stepBlock.map(Block => ( <StepsBuilder  key={steps} />))}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Given stepBlock value to be integer.

lets say `stepBlock === 5`

```
{[...Array(stepBlock)].map((e, i) => <StepsBuilder  key={steps} />)}
```

Comment: So I have this in a section which is hidden via a Boolean hook. When the user runs the form submission it unhides that section however even though I input 7 steps it will only render 1 of the component.. Is this because I'm simply unhiding it by sectioning the Boolean to true?

Comment: ok so I see the issue is I have "const [steps, setSteps] = useState(Number);" 

when I changed your code to this: {[...Array(steps)].map((e, i) => <StepsBuilder  key={steps} />)}

and I change Number to just 3 inside of that const it  shows 3 of that component. So my issue is its not updating the child component upon updating the value of steps. any ideas?

Comment: ok my issue was bc i had it defined as a number. I made it a string then converted it to a Int and it is getting a array of say 7 such as this: (7) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].. for stepBlock however it doesn't result in 7 StepBuilder components still only one even though there are clearly 7 numbers inside the array.

Comment: Chuck stepBlock inside console.log and see what value you are getting. Also check the typeof value. Above code working fine when you replace stepBlock with some number

Comment: Yeah it does work if you do that however I discovered my issue is its not updating it using a dynamic variable that is pulled from what the user enters. basically it won't update and change.

Comment: If you can update your question with the code then I can help you

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct bc it does work. However I believe I just need to use a different component and pull the newly created data in that in order to do what I want instead of trying everything in the same spot. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose stepBlock is a list of items that you want to send as properties to StepsBuilder component.

```
 <div>
     {stepBlock.map(block => ( <StepsBuilder  key={steps} block={block} />))}
 </div>
```

Inside StepsBuilder component you will have block as property:

```
function StepsBuilder(props) {
  console.log(props.block)
}
```

Comment: actually stepblock is the res from the user input form. I tried using that.. I'm basically attempting to say if the user inputs 5 steps. .then I want to render out 5 of the stepbuilder component. I just was attempting to do it thru mapping..